# Cancel Duplicate Request NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am developing a news application.I am using a table view to show the news. To download data from the server I am using **sendAsynchronousRequest** .

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
         {
             if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
             {
                 downloadedItem = [GNNewsItems saveDataToModel:data];
                 if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(receivedResponse:)])
                 {
                     [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receivedResponse:) withObject:downloadedItem waitUntilDone:NO];
                 }
             }
             else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
             {
                 // Data not downloaded
             }
             else if (error != nil)
             {
                // error
             }
        }];
```

So far so good. Now consider a case:

1. User opens the app.
2. Table View send's a request to download the content of the first cell. *Let us assume it takes 10 seconds to download the data.*
3. User scrolls the table view to the 5th cell.
4. Table view sends the request for 5th cell.
5. Now user comes back to the first cell but the content of the initial request sent by cell 1 is not yet downloaded.
6. Table view will send a duplicate request for the first cell.

How can I cancel the duplicate request from the table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `NSMutableArray` which will contain the **indexPath** of the cell  for which request has already been initiated. Before initiating the web request for the a new in a cell check in the if request is already initiated or not. If not then initiate it else do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your design description sounds like you are not using a standard Model/View design paradigm. You should store the headlines and other associated data, such as the full story or link to same in some kind of datastore, e.g. an array or CoreData etc. That object is what requests stories and updates data elements. Then it only does it once and in the background, and once gotten, it is done.

Then the tableView uses that datastore to populate table cells. It is a VERY bad design to be making over the air requests for stories each time a cell scrolls into view. It has the design issues you just mentioned plus it is very wasteful of users bandwidth and your server resources.